# Parse json without changing the object structure

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and i want to parse a JSON into an instance of this class:

```
class Client {
    name_ =null;  
    age_ =null
    something_=null ;

   get Name()
   {
       return _name ; 
   }
   set Name(val) {
       _name = val ; 

   }
   get Age()
   {
       return _age ; 
   }
   set Age(val) {
       _age = val ; 

   }

   get Something()
   {
       return something_ ; 
   }
   set Something(val) {
    something_ = val ; 

   }
}
```

i tried this :

```
let client1 = new Client() ;
let js =`
  {
    "Name": "Estes Benjamin",
    "Age": 31
  }
`; 

client1 = JSON.parse(js);
console.log(client1);
```

this code give me this result :

```
Object { Name: "Estes Benjamin", Age: 31 }
```

but what i'm looking for is this (the original object populated with the JSON content )

```
Object { Name: "Estes Benjamin", Age: 31, Something: null }
```

Comment: `Object.assign(new Client, JSON.parse(js))`?

Comment: You're reassigning the `client1` variable, overwriting it with the result of `JSON.parse(js)` giving it a completely new value.

Comment: I'd start with making sure the class syntax is correct and all the properties have the same name. (You're mixing prefix and postfix underscores.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`client1 = JSON.parse(js)` completely replaces the value that was in `client1`, so the `Client` instance is no longer there.

You can update the properties on that instance instead via [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
let client1 = new Client();
let json =`
  {
    "Name": "Estes Benjamin",
    "Age": 31
  }
`; 

Object.assign(client1, JSON.parse(json));
console.log(client1);
```

Live Example *(with the updated `Client` code shown below)*:

```js
class Client {
    _name = null;  
    _age = null;
    _something = null;

    get Name() {
       return this._name; 
    }

    set Name(val) {
       this._name = val; 
    }

    get Age() {
       return this._age; 
    }

    set Age(val) {
       this._age = val; 
    }

    get Something() {
       return this._something; 
    }

    set Something(val) {
        this._something = val;
    }
}

let client1 = new Client();
let json =`
  {
    "Name": "Estes Benjamin",
    "Age": 31
  }
`; 

Object.assign(client1, JSON.parse(json));
console.log(client1);
```

That takes all of the properties from the newly-created object from `JSON.parse` and copies them into the `Client` instance in `client1`.

Also note that as Ivar said, there are some issues with `Client`. The main two are:

1. You're sometimes using `_` after the property name, other times using it before.
2. In JavaScript, to access a property on the instance, you have to explicitly reference the instance. In a method, you typically do that with the `this` keyword.

Here's a version with those fixed:

```
class Client {
    _name = null;  
    _age = null;
    _something = null;

    get Name() {
       return this._name; 
    }

    set Name(val) {
       this._name = val; 
    }

    get Age() {
       return this._age; 
    }

    set Age(val) {
       this._age = val; 
    }

    get Something() {
       return this._something; 
    }

    set Something(val) {
        this._something = val;
    }
}
```

Beyond that, though, some observations (mostly just FYI):

- Properties prefixed with `_` are still public and can still be accessed directly. (For instance, `client1._age` would give us `31` in the example above.) (JavaScript does have actual private fields now, though they're very new.)
- There's not a lot of point to those accessor properties vs. just using a data property as the class stands now. But if you were adding side-effects or logging or something, or only providing a getter but no setter, those are (or can be) use cases for accessor properties.
- Even accessor properties in JavaScript are generally written with a lower case initial letter.
- Your code relies on the relatively-new [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) proposal (but it's broadly-supported other than in obsolete browsers like Internet Explorer 11). You're using that feature where you define your instance properties (`_name`, etc.). Prior to the class fields stuff being added, you had to do that inside the constructor as an assignment (`this._name = null;`).

Just FWIW, if you wanted to use private fields (which, again, are very new):

```
class Client {
    #name = null;
    // ...
    get name() {
        return this.#name;
    }
    set name(value) {
        this.#name = value;
    }
    // ...
}
```

With that, `client1.#age` is an error. You can't access it outside the class.

Comment: Is `Object.assign` smart enough to use the setter methods on the target, or does it completely replace the getter/setter functions with a "basic" property?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - `Object.assign` does an assignment operation, and so it ends up calling the setter. (`Object.defineProperties` would redefine the properties instead of calling the setters.)